# Webpack: Как поместить все функции/переменные с ключевым словом export в одну глобальную переменную при сборке?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6

Я меняю способ сборки typescript библиотеки с *gulp concat* + *typescript compiler* на *Webpack*. И внедряю *es2015 modules*.

Теперь библиотека может быть использована с `require/import`. А также необходимо оставить возможность использовать библиотеку классическим добавлением скрипта в *html header*.

Раньше, все *functions/variables* были спрятаны в глобальную переменную `Survey`. Для этого использовались *неймспейсы typescript* `namespace Survey {}` и все классы или переменные, которые хотелось отдать наружу, имели ключевое слово export.

Я удалил неймспейсы и перевёл всё на *es2015 модули* и теперь, чтобы получить ту же глобальную переменную я был вынужден включить импорты всеx необходимыx классов/переменных во входную точку *webpack* сборки:

https://github.com/dmitrykurmanov/surveyjs/blob/master/webpack/reactStandardIndex.js

Есть ли какой-то другой способ достичь того же, но без создания такого огромного и ужасного файла?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Суть в том что реально нужно собрать все нужные зависимости в одном месте, чтобы потом их отдать `пучком`. Но отдавать нужно только те зависимости, которые реально будут нужны снаружи.

А чтобы жуткий рулон стал менее ужасен, то можно экспортировать не импортируя -

```
export { Dependence } from ".....";
export Dependence from ".....";
export * as Dependence from ".....";
// и т.п
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Это поможет сделать файл не таким ужасным, но почему-то если использовать такой синтаксис: `export Default, { Dependence } from ".....";` то всё падает с ошибкой `Unexpected token`. Если же делать два экспорта: `export Default from "..."` и `export { Dependence } from ".....";` то всё нормально.

Comment: Выяснил, что такого синтаксиса попросту нет, что странно конечно. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: Странно, у меня работает, но правда на минимальном примере. Попробуйте так - `export { default as Default,  Dependence } from "...";`.

Comment: так работает да. Можно еще export * from "..."; если нужно всё добавить